# Multiple NSMutableParagraphStyle in UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring

In my app i need to show the **different paragraph style** for each and every paragraph in UITextView.

like if for **first paragraph** that user write has **headIndent 10.0** then **second** paragraph has **26.0** and **third** paragraph has **7.0** and **fourth** paragraph has **0.0** and **etc...** .

and if i did this by if else condition then **typing speed getting slow**.

what should i do for this ? that typing speed will not become slow and i can set the different paragraph style for different paragraph.

I am putting my small code which is in **shouldChangeTextInRange** method to get idea about the problem...

```
NSArray *sampleArrToGetattrStr = [txtViewOfNotes.text componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet newlineCharacterSet]];

for (int i=0; i<[sampleArrToGetattrStr count]; i++) {
    NSString *strtostoreLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[sampleArrToGetattrStr objectAtIndex:i]];
    varStaringPointOfString = (int)strtostoreLength.length + varEndingPointOfString;

    if ([strtostoreLength hasPrefix:@"  \u2022   "])
    {
        NSLog(@"if %d == %d == %d == %lu",i,varStaringPointOfString,varEndingPointOfString,(unsigned long)strtostoreLength.length);

        paragraphStyleForBulletInNewPresMethod.headIndent=26.0;
        paragraphStyleForBulletInNewPresMethod.minimumLineHeight = 0.f;
        paragraphStyleForBulletInNewPresMethod.maximumLineHeight = 16.f;
        paragraphStyleForBulletInNewPresMethod.paragraphSpacing = 7.5;
        paragraphStyleForBulletInNewPresMethod.lineSpacing = 5.0;
        paragraphStyleForBulletInNewPresMethod.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        paragraphStyleForBulletInNewPresMethod.tailIndent=305.0;

        [mutattstr1  addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyleForBulletInNewPresMethod range:NSMakeRange(varEndingPointOfString, strtostoreLength.length)];

    }
{
        NSLog(@"else %d == %d == %d == %lu",i,varStaringPointOfString,varEndingPointOfString,(unsigned long)strtostoreLength.length);

        paragraphStyle.headIndent=0.f;
        paragraphStyle.minimumLineHeight = 0.f;
        paragraphStyle.maximumLineHeight = 16.f;
        paragraphStyle.paragraphSpacing = 7.5;
        paragraphStyle.lineSpacing = 5.0;
        paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode=NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
        paragraphStyle.tailIndent=305.0;

        [mutattstr1  addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value:paragraphStyle range:NSMakeRange(varEndingPointOfString, strtostoreLength.length)];

    }

    varEndingPointOfString = varStaringPointOfString;

    strtostoreLength =@"";
}
[txtViewOfNotes setAttributedText:mutattstr1];
```

Any kind of help will appreciate.